# Should all javascript be put inside a load() on body event?

Tags: javascript, performance, correctness

Should I put all this inside a load() body event so that it loads after the page has rendered and the DOM objects have been created? (I did find I had to use .innerhtml rather than .value for it to work.) If so how...

(*I know this is rubbish code, but it is better than my last attempt and worse than my next attempt. Once I get some time to comeback to this I will recreate it using a literal constructor with internal functions. I am not looking to take this Javascript any further in functionality. The back-end php I have will handle security and checks)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//To get the price of a product applying discount
function getPrice(location,quantity)
{
    //Get the product choice
    var e = document.getElementById("productList["+location+"]");
    var productSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    //TODO: Determine discounts based on product choice
    switch(productSelected)
    {
        case '0':
            return 0;
        case '1':
            return 10;
        case '2':
            return 15;
    }
    return null;
}

//To update product only
function updateProduct(location)
{
    updateRow(location,document.getElementById("quantity["+location+"]").value);
}

//To update only that row
function updateRow(location,quantity)
{
    //Check Quantity is a valid Number and also not a float or negative
    if (!isNaN(quantity) && parseFloat(quantity) && isFinite(quantity) && (quantity >= 0)) {
        quantity = Math.floor(quantity);
    } else {
        quantity = 0;
    };

    //Update the quantity input field to whatever quantity is - Investigate later!
    document.getElementById("quantity["+location+"]").value = quantity;

    //Store old Price for changing total
    var oldTotal = document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML;
    var oldLinePrice = document.getElementById("linePrice["+location+"]").innerHTML;

    //Calculate and Store Prices to adjust the total
    var productPrice = getPrice(location,quantity).toFixed(2);
    var newLinePrice = (quantity*productPrice).toFixed(2);

    //Apply  Updates
    document.getElementById("unitPrice["+location+"]").innerHTML = productPrice;
    document.getElementById("linePrice["+location+"]").innerHTML = newLinePrice;
    document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = (oldTotal-oldLinePrice+parseFloat(newLinePrice)).toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Code that needs to run after the DOM is loaded should be in the load function. I realize this is a tautology, but what other answer do you expect?

Comment: Those are just function definitions, you could put them wherever you want in your code. Just remember to call them after the page loads.

Comment: @d4rkpr1nc3 Thats what I thought, but I could only use .innerHTML in some places rather than .value which I thought was due to the DOM not having made the elements yet.

Comment: the `value` attribute only applies to any form element. For any other HTML element user `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to put any `getElement` calls, or calls to functions that get elements, in a load function.

Comment: So because nearly all these functions have a 'getElementById' in them I need to add all this to a load function

Comment: @WilliamJames The functions themselves do not have to be defined inside an onload style function, they simply needs to be called after the dom is loaded.

Comment: @asawyer I see. I think that makes sense. I am just baffled now then why I can't use .value rather than .innerHTML in some places.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you could, but that then could delay some js code from getting started working on parts of your .html coding which get loaded first. It also makes code be indented more than it needs to be, causing a readability issue.

Comment: No - the code presented is only a collection of uncalled (at the time of load) functions, there's no actual function attached to the `load` event that executes when the page loads.  Events should be used for what they are intended for, not for storage of petty functions.